# SecretClient class in azure-keyvault-secrets python package throws unexpected errir

Tags: python, azure, azure-keyvault

I've been trying to get my python script to retrieve a secret from an Azure key vault. For the authentication I've been using the ServicePrincipal credential and the Azure-keyvault-secrets package which comes with a SecretClient class. But it's throwing an error which might be because of any updates in the python package. 
Could anyone point out what's going wrong?

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

CLIENT_ID '...' #app_id
TENANT_ID = '...'
KEY = '...'


credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    secret=KEY,
    tenant=TENANT_ID
)
vault_url = '...'
secret_name = "..."
secret_version = '...'


client = SecretClient(vault_url=vault_url, credential=credentials)
secret = client.get_secret(secret_name)
```

It gives the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "key-vault.py", line 23, in <module>
    secret = client.get_secret("cromaprivate128")
  File "/Users/rishavputatunda/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 71, in wrapper_use_tracer
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rishavputatunda/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/azure/keyvault/secrets/_client.py", line 71, in get_secret
    **kwargs
  File "/Users/rishavputatunda/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/azure/keyvault/secrets/_shared/_generated/v7_0/operations/_key_vault_client_operations.py", line 1621, in get_secret
    pipeline_response = self._client._pipeline.run(request, stream=False, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rishavputatunda/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 208, in run
    return first_node.send(pipeline_request)  # type: ignore
  File "/Users/rishavputatunda/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 80, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/Users/rishavputatunda/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 80, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/Users/rishavputatunda/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 80, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/Users/rishavputatunda/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_redirect.py", line 157, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/Users/rishavputatunda/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_retry.py", line 418, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/Users/rishavputatunda/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/azure/keyvault/secrets/_shared/challenge_auth_policy.py", line 67, in send
    self._handle_challenge(request, challenge)
  File "/Users/rishavputatunda/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/azure/keyvault/secrets/_shared/challenge_auth_policy.py", line 91, in _handle_challenge
    access_token = self._credential.get_token(scope)
AttributeError: 'ServicePrincipalCredentials' object has no attribute 'get_token'
```

Comment: Hi. We cannot use the ```ServicePrincipalCredentials``` to create a ```SecretClient```.  Because the ServicePrincipalCredentials cannot provide the access token. Please try to use the Credentials provided by sdk [```azure.identity```](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity?view=azure-python). For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/quick-create-python

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing it out. I was able to do it with azure.identity.

Comment: Since it is useful for you, could you please [mark my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? It can help persons who have similar issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We cannot use the ServicePrincipalCredentials to create a SecretClient. Because the ServicePrincipalCredentials cannot provide the access token. If you want to access key vault, please try to use the Credentials provided by sdk [`azure.identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity?view=azure-python).

For example
1. Create a service principal with Azure CLI

```
az login
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp"   --sdk-auth
```

[image]

2. Set access policy

```
az keyvault set-policy -n <your-unique-keyvault-name> --spn <clientId-of-your-service-principal> --secret-permissions delete get list set --key-permissions create decrypt delete encrypt get list unwrapKey wrapKe
```

3. code

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
    from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
tenant_id="<your sp tenant>" 
client_id="<your sp client id>"
client_secret="<your sp client secret>"
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)

 secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url="https://my-key-vault.vault.azure.net/", credential=credential)

 secret = secret_client.get_secret("secret-name")

    print(secret.name)
    print(secret.value)
```

Comment: @RishavPutatunda Since your issue has been resolved, could you please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? It may help more people.